# Why my mother-ship core cannot blast the photon cannon?

Tags: starcraft-2

In LotV my mothership core is not able to cast photon cannon: I do have enough energy, spell is available, but hitting it and selecting Nexus doesn't give me anything.

Please advise how to cast photon cannon spell by MS core.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the [Photon Overcharge](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Mothership_core) ability that in Heart of the Swarm allowed your Nexus to shoot nearby enemies.

In Legacy of the Void, this ability was changed to be placed on pylons instead of the Nexus.

The ability now reads:

> Energizes the target Pylon's khaydarin crystal, turning it into a powerful long-range weapon for 11 seconds that deals 30 damage.

Note also that the range has been shortened in Legacy of the Void to 7.

Comment: ah.... I felt somethings like that... just did not have any time in the game to read description properly :) Thanks!